# Gettext and Zend Translate, using multiple languages

Tags: zend-framework, translation, gettext, zend-translate, po

I have the following setup in my application Bootstrap.php

```
 protected function _initTranslation()
{
    $langPath = APPLICATION_PATH.'/languages/';
    $translate = new Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext($langPath . 'site-ro.mo', 'ro');
    $translate = new Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext($langPath . 'site-en.mo', 'en');
    $translate->setLocale('en');
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
}
```

and in my add.phtml file I have it like this

```
 <label for="page_title" class="sr-only"><?= $this->translate("Page title") ?></label>
```

I know this works only if i have the setLocale to 'en' and if there exists an translation. But i don't know how to set for multiple translations and also not to throw errors if the .po file doesn't have a translation.

Answer (score 0):

look at here:
[Additional features for translation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.additional.html#zend.translate.additional.languages)

You can always change your language in controller by these code :

```
    $translate = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
    $translate->setLocale('ro');
```

after that your locale will be changed.